# Clicking a lot of website links in Google Maps, then sent through multiple URL redirects, and lastly to a page that made my laptop start beeping?

Tags: network, web-browser, attacks, xss, javascript

I was in Google maps clicking on all the website links listed in the side panel, looking at every website really fast. Note, they were all tattoo parlors. One of the links I clicked bounced me through a series of 4 URL redirects, apparently affiliate networks, one of which was Amazon something, and then lastly to a page which made my laptop start beeping. This page displayed a popup window stating my browsers close button had been disabled for my safety and that I should call the number listed to save my computer from infection. I hit alt + f4 and closed the window. Then returned to the same maps page and clicked the same link, nothing happened.

I went onto said website and and used Chrome dev tools to inspect the site. I saw no suspicious Javascript files and nothing in the cookie directory.

What the heck was this and how can I find out where the hijack came from?

Comment: There's no way we can answer this.

Comment: @NeilSmithline What? You've never gone from Google Maps to hardware beep codes in a few clicks before?

Comment: "I was working my way down the list clicking on every website link" well you weren't on Google after you clicked the link, so its likely you stumbled upon some poorly constructed/hijacked tattoo parlor web presence (not surprising at all IMO). They often use cookies to send users at a certain rate to ad-generating sites, for their own gain, so repeated visits not producing the same results is common. Sometimes its intentional, sometimes not.

Comment: Welcome to hijacked websites and redirects to malvertising and exploit servers. You clicked a link to a hacked website that randomly redirects. It delays discovery when they do this.

Comment: While I think your updates make the question better, they don't fix the root problem. Without more information, information that you don't have, we can only make wild guesses at what happened. Unless you're able to reproduce it and provide us with details, the problem won't ever be resolved. This is not your fault, it's just the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that this has anything to do with google.

According to your description google maps was only your starting point and from there you've opened the different websites for the various business. Some of these sites might be either infected or they contained ads and through these direct infections or the [malvertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising) you got served some [Scareware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scareware) which tried to use social engineering to make you install some software.
Nothing really special and such things happens unfortunately way too often. And it is also common and intendet that you cannot easily reproduce it.